# Is it safe to have virtual memory in servers?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, sql

I'm not sure if it's safe to have virtual memory (pagefile.sys) in servers?

Safe in the sense of:
Would it affect the data in the cache that is being handled by RAM? Does it conflict if it will be called?

Specs:
Server - Lenovo System x3250 M6 Rack Server
RAID - 1
Physical Memory: 32Gb

Would really appreciate everyone's input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly OK to have virtual memory in a server. Ideally the pagefile size should be approximately 1.5 times the size of RAM.

Comment: Thank you Soumendra, will deploy a virtual memory on our current server. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if it's safe to have virtual memory (pagefile.sys) in servers?

It absolutely is. Even better, it is *highly recommended* to employ some reasonable sized swapping space.

> Would it affect the data in the cache that is being handled by RAM?

The is no such thing as "the cache"; usually you have L1/L2/L3 Cache, a filesystem cache, storage cache, cached libraries and much more.

Calling conflicts in a filesystem cache (usually resides in RAM), as I understand you are asking for, are almost impossible. The kernel (of modern operatin systems) redirects logical calls to the "right" physical objects, as he is the one asked about anyway. I am positive that you don't have to worry about this in almost any ususual use cases.

Comment: Thank you bjoster for clarifying.